# Cron triggers fires immediately after resume

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I am adding Triggers to my `Quartz.NET` scheduler using statements like this:

```
ITrigger t = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity(triggerName, triggerGroup)
              .WithCronSchedule(cron)
              .Build();
```

Say, the cron expression is one to fire every 3 minutes:

```
0 0/3 * 1/1 * ? *
```

In my program, the user can `Pause` and `Resume` a job that has been scheduled with the above schedules.

What I see is that every time I resume a pause job, the job is executed once *immediately* after resume. This has started to worry me. Is this behavior normal or is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens due to misfire policy. Trigger missed its fire time, is considered misfired and then action is taken according to misfire policy.

You can adjust triggers misfire policy when creating the trigger. Please see the tutorial for more information.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-triggers.html

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html